# How to build caffe after changes to Makefile.config

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I realized that i have not uncommented below line in Makefile.config

```
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1
```

I uncommented it to match with my requirement. Now how to build it, so that changes are reflected in caffe.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to run

```
make all && make pycaffe && make test && make runtest
```

The problem is that sometimes make doesn't consider Makefile.config as a file that influences the build, so you should add `make clean` before the `make all` command.